# bash script to select multiple file formats at once for encode process

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have a BASH script I downloaded (that works) to do some video conversions using handbrake-CLI but at the moment it only allows conversion from a single file format at a time avi to mkv only.  I would like to be able to have it convert any type of input file (avi,wmv,flv...to mkv ) all at once instead of changing the script each time for each input format. How can I adjust the bash script to allow this?

So how can I get this bash script with the line **input_file_type="avi"** to work with **input_file_type="avi,wmv,flv,mp4"**

PS: I tried posting the bash script but the format got all messed up if someone knows how to post a bash script to the forum with correct formatting let me know I'll post it here instead of the link below

[http://pastebin.com/hzyxnsYY][1]

Paste the code here:

```
#!/bin/sh

###############################################################################
#
# Script to recursively search a directory and batch convert all files of a given
# file type into another file type via HandBrake conversion.
#
# To run in your environment set the variables:
#   hbcli - Path to your HandBrakeCLI
#
#   source_dir - Starting directory for recursive search
#
#   input_file_type - Input file type to search for
#
#   output_file_type  - Output file type to convert into
#
#
# Change log:
# 2014-01-27: Initial release.  Tested on ubuntu 13.10.
#
###############################################################################

hbcli=HandBrakeCLI
source_dir="/media/rt/1tera_ext/1_Video_Stuff/1 Documentary"
#source_dir="/media/rt/1tera_ext/1_Video_Stuff/1 Nova and bbc/Carbon diamonds"



input_file_type="avi"
output_file_type="mkv"

echo "# Using HandBrakeCLI at "$hbcli
echo "# Using source directory " "$source_dir"
echo "# Converting "$input_file_type" to "$output_file_type

# Convert from one file to another
convert() {
        # The beginning part, echo "" | , is really important.  Without that, HandBrake exits the while loop.
        #echo "" | $hbcli -i "$1" -o "$2" --preset="Universal";
        echo "" | $hbcli -i "$1" -t 1 --angle 1 -c 1 -o "$2"  -f mkv  --decomb --loose-anamorphic  --modulus 2 -e x264 -q 20 --cfr -a 1,1 -E faac,copy:ac3 -6 dpl2,auto -R Auto,Auto -B 160,0 -D 0,0 --gain 0,0 --audio-fallback ffac3 --x264-profile=high  --h264-level="4.1"  --verbose=1
        #echo "" | $hbcli -i "$1" -t 1 --angle 1 -c 1 -o "$2"  -f mkv  --decomb -w 640 --loose-anamorphic  --modulus 2 -e x264 -q 20 --cfr -a 1,1 -E faac,copy:ac3 -6 dpl2,auto -R Auto,Auto -B 160,0 -D 0,0 --gain 0,0 --audio-fallback ffac3 --x264-profile=high  --h264-level="4.1"  --verbose=1

}

# Find the files and pipe the results into the read command.  The read command properly handles spaces in directories and files names.
find "$source_dir" -name *.$input_file_type | while read in_file
do
        echo "Processing…"
        echo ">Input  "$in_file

        # Replace the file type
        out_file=$(echo $in_file|sed "s/\(.*\.\)$input_file_type/\1$output_file_type/g")
        echo ">Output "$out_file

        # Convert the file
        convert "$in_file" "$out_file"

        if [ $? != 0 ]
        then
            echo "$in_file had problems" >> handbrake-errors.log
        fi

        echo ">Finished "$out_file "\n\n"
done

echo "DONE CONVERTING FILES"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the conversion command is the same for all file types, you can use a single `find` like this:

```
find "$source_dir" -type f -regex ".*\.\(avi\|wmv\|flv\|mp4\)" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' in_file
do

done
```

Alternatively, create an array of file types that you are interested in and loop over them:

```
input_file_types=(avi wmv flv mp4)

# loop over the types and convert
for input_file_type in "${input_file_types[@]}"
do
    find "$source_dir" -name "*.$input_file_type" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' in_file
    do

    done
done
```

In order to correctly handle filenames containing whitespace and newline characters, you should use null delimited output. That's what the `-print0` and `read -d $'\0'` is for.

Comment: I get an Syntax error: "(" unexpected when in the line input_file_types=(avi wmv flv mp4)  should these be in quotes instead?

Comment: no, you don't need quotes. You're probably not using `bash` (or using an old version) so arrays aren't supported.

Answer (score 1):

You can use OR( `-o`) operator in `find` lane.

E.g.

```
find "$source_dir" -name *.avi -o -name *wmv -o -name *.flv -o -name *.mp4 | while read in_file
```

Answer (score 1):

If run by bash:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

input_file_type="avi|wmv|flv|mp4"

find "$source_dir" -type f|egrep "$input_file_type" | while read in_file
do
        echo "Processing…"
        echo ">Input  "$in_file

        # Replace the file type
        out_file=$(in_file%.*}.${output_file_type}   # replace file type with different command. 
        echo ">Output "$out_file

        # Convert the file
        convert "$in_file" "$out_file"

        if [ $? != 0 ]
        then
            echo "$in_file had problems" >> handbrake-errors.log
        fi

        echo ">Finished "$out_file "\n\n"
done
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's the final code that may help someone else, sorry about the link I didn't know how to paste bash script in here without the format getting all messed up

[Link to the final code](http://pastebin.com/rDC0cStv)

> 

```
#!/bin/bash

###############################################################################
#execute using bash mkvconv.sh

# Script to recursively search a directory and batch convert all files of a given
# file type into another file type via HandBrake conversion.
#
# To run in your environment set the variables:
#   hbcli - Path to your HandBrakeCLI
#
#   source_dir - Starting directory for recursive search
#
#   input_file_types - Input file types to search for
#
#   output_file_type  - Output file type to convert into
#
#
# Change log:
# 2014-01-27: Initial release.  Tested on ubuntu 13.10.
#http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21404059/bash-script-to-select-multiple-file-formats-at-once-for-encode-process/21404530#21404530
###############################################################################

hbcli=HandBrakeCLI
source_dir="/media/rt/1tera_ext/1_Video_Stuff/1 Nova and bbc/Carbon diamonds"


input_file_types=(avi wmv flv mp4 webm mov mpg)
output_file_type="mkv"

echo "# Using HandBrakeCLI at "$hbcli
echo "# Using source directory " "$source_dir"
echo "# Converting "$input_file_types" to "$output_file_type

# Convert from one file to another
convert() {
        # The beginning part, echo "" | , is really important.  Without that, HandBrake exits the while loop.
        #echo "" | $hbcli -i "$1" -o "$2" --preset="Universal"; # dont use with preses things are left out
        echo "" | $hbcli -i "$1" -t 1 --angle 1 -c 1 -o "$2"  -f mkv  --decomb --loose-anamorphic  --modulus 2 -e x264 -q 20 --cfr -a 1,1 -E faac,copy:ac3 -6 dpl2,auto -R Auto,Auto -B 160,0 -D 0,0 --gain 0,0 --audio-fallback ffac3 --x264-profile=high  --h264-level="4.1"  --verbose=1

}
# loop over the types and convert
for input_file_types in "${input_file_types[@]}"
do

        # Find the files and pipe the results into the read command.  The read command properly handles spaces in directories and files names.
        #find "$source_dir" -name *.$input_file_type | while read in_file
        find "$source_dir" -name "*.$input_file_types" -print0 | while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' in_file
        #In order to correctly handle filenames containing whitespace and newline characters, you should use null delimited output. That's what the -print0 and read -d $'\0' is for.
        do
                echo "Processing…"
                echo ">Input  "$in_file

                # Replace the file type
                out_file=$(echo $in_file|sed "s/\(.*\.\)$input_file_types/\1$output_file_type/g")
                echo ">Output "$out_file

                # Convert the file
                convert "$in_file" "$out_file"

                if [ $? != 0 ]
                then
                    echo "$in_file had problems" >> handbrake-errors.log
                fi

                echo ">Finished "$out_file "\n\n"
        done
done
echo "DONE CONVERTING FILES"
```